# Debugging a Deadlock with !dlk command returns unkown thread name

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, deadlock, windbg

Im trying to debug a deadlock in my process by using the SOSEX command !dlk
I get the following output:

```
*DEADLOCK DETECTED*

CLR thread 0xac holds the lock on SyncBlock 00000012ac132068 OBJ:00000012830d66a0[System.Object]
and is waiting for the lock on SyncBlock 00000012ae4ba6b8 OBJ:00000012808391f8[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib],[CaptureServices.GenericInfrastructure.Controlling.CapManager.MO.CallRecorder.ICallRecorder, Capture Manager]]]

CLR thread 0x9a holds the lock on SyncBlock 00000012ae4ba6b8 OBJ:00000012808391f8[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib],[CaptureServices.GenericInfrastructure.Controlling.CapManager.MO.CallRecorder.ICallRecorder, Capture Manager]]]
and is waiting for the lock on SyncBlock 00000012ac132068 OBJ:00000012830d66a0[System.Object]
```

I would like to be able to get the call stack of these threads, but I cant find the threads IDs (0xac, 0x9a) in the lists of threads.
I tried the following commands, and the above threads are not listed in any of the results:

1. **~** - should shows all threads (managed and unmanaged)
2. **~*e!clrstack** - should show the call stack of all threads
3. **~*e!dumpstack** - dump all managed threads

is there another way to see the call stack of the threads found in the deadlock that I might be missing? I even tried to convert the thread ID to decimal but failed to find a matching thread ID.

thanks

Comment: `!threads` shows managed threads. Maybe you find it there. However, 9A is 154, that's a large number

Comment: thanks - I found the following article that explains that the thread ID shown in the result is the CLR ID in decimal form: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/04/27/debugging-a-classic-readerwriterlock-deadlock-with-sosex-dll/

Comment: Ok, fine. Then, please post your finding as an answer. You can then accept your own answer and mark this case as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [following article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/04/27/debugging-a-classic-readerwriterlock-deadlock-with-sosex-dll/)
helped me how to read the results of the !dlk command. 
according to the article, if for example we found a deadlock in thread 0xac:

```
CLR **thread 0xac** holds the lock on SyncBlock 00000012ac132068 OBJ:00000012830d66a0[System.Object]
```

The results of the !thread command have 3 "IDs" columns:

1. logical thread ID (1st column)
2. CLR ID (2nd column)
3. OSID (3rd column)

The thread ID in !dlk is actually the CLR ID in the !thread results:
(ac) = 172. CLR id 172 is thread 177.

```
0:000> !threads
                                                                                                        Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
 177  172 1188 00000012abfcaee0  3029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000012f0e94d70 3     MTA (Threadpool Worker)
```

now I could switch to thread 177 by command: **~177s**

and see the thread's call stack by command: **!clrstack**